# TCP, UDP, etc. works, HTTP(S) does not

Tags: linux, tcp, laptop, http

I have been trying to set up Debian Jessie on an old Dell Inspiron 300m. Right now the problem I have is, the ethernet connection only works partially.

- ICMP works. I can ping IPs and FQDNs.
- UDP works. I can get an IP via DHCP, and an FQDN from my home DNS server.
- TCP does not work. I cannot open TCP connections to any service anywhere, and netstat's list of TCP connections is utterly empty - no local client ports, no loopback stuff, nothing at all.

iptables does not have anything beyond the normal UFW block-unsolicited-inbound stuff. This happens with both the onboard NIC and a USB-to-ethernet dongle I bought. The onboard is a Broadcom Tigon3, and for firmware for it is installed; I'm not sure what the dongle is, but it works on every Linux 3.x host I've tried it on.

Also, the kernel is the typical Jessie linux-image-586 package; not 686-pae, because the laptop has a Pentium M. I don't think that should make a difference, but who knows.

Update: It seems like this is a problem not with TCP, but with HTTP(S). I can connect out to servers on TCP ports, but there are no responses to HTTP requests. I've therefore updated the title.

The issue is still limited to only one computer (the old Inspiron).

Comment: Can you please post the output of *sysctl -a | grep tcp*?

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/a2DHSjVd

Comment: Can you connect to localhost? E.g., `nc -l -p 1234` and then `nc 127.0.0.1 1234`.

Comment: BTW: My first guess (by far!) is that you actually have a firewall rule that is messing things up. My second guess would be (if it only applies to remote, not local, connections) something with TCP offload on the Ethernet card. My third guess is that you've done something crazy, e.g., compile a kernel w/o TCP support (not sure that's even possible). Do you get any error messages, either from the program trying to listen/connect or in `dmesg`?

Comment: Firewall rules are, as I said, all default for UFW. The kernel is the default one. I'll see if I can connect to localhost when I get home...

Comment: It is clear from the output of *sysctl -a* that you have the  conntrack module loaded, which is a bit more than *the normal UFW block-unsolicited-inbound stuff*. Could you try by disabling UFW altogether?

Comment: ... Huh? conntrack is how iptables blocks **unsolicited** inbound traffic. Unless UFW is using the state module, which IIRC is deprecated now. But I will try that too when I get home.

Comment: @derobert tried netcat, I can connect to localhost... And also out to kernel.org. I think this may not be a networking problem but an application one, with apt-get and some other programs not resolving hosts correctly? Not sure.